# Can't use the OLAP cube using an established external data connection in Excel, but I can create a new connection with the same analysis server

Tags: excel, ssas, cube, excel-external-data

I've updated my company's cube earlier today by adding a new fact table and a corresponding measure Group in the cube.

This change deployed successfully, and the processing of the cube was successful.

However, I've had a strange error which I do not know if it comes from this change (it should not be correlated?) which is that when I tried to use a report on SSRS with the cube as a data source I got the error that "either the user xxx does not have the permission to access the database or the database does not exist" which seemed odd, seeing that I could browse the cube in SSMS.

This resolved itself though. "All of a sudden" it just worked.

Trying to connect to the cube using Excel the same issue arises, however. When I want to use an established external data Connection I get the error that I don't have access to the database, or that it does not exist. Again, I have the permissions (I am an administrator), and I can browse the cube in SSMS and use it as a source in SSRS.

When I import the same cube from a new analysis server Connection in Excel, however - it works!

How can this be? Do I have to import the cube again after it has been deployed, instead of just processed? Seeing that many people will use the cube as a source in Excel - do they have to import it once again or can it be achieved in some other manner?

I am not sure how to get rid of the error regarding the users not being able to connect to the cube, from the Connection Before it was deployed, but that it is possible with "post-deployed" version.

Regards,

Cenderze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the settings under `Project -> Deployment` were altered. Instead of deploying the project to the original database, it was deployed on to a database with an excessive `M` letter, causing the Connection strings in Excel etc. to not be correct anymore.

I'll let this be an answer in case someone else gets the same error, however it seems unlikely.